# How do you write your controller in MVC pattern without PHP frameworks?

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, model-view-controller

How will you write your controller in MVC pattern without PHP frameworks?

This is the simplest version of my controller,

```
//Controller
class Controller
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function clicked() {
        $this->model->string = "Updated Data, thanks to MVC and PHP!";
    }
}
```

As you can see that **only model** is passed into my controller as its dependency.

This is how I understand the controller in MVC pattern which can be referenced in these following articles,

https://r.je/views-are-not-templates.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

PHP framework developers probably disagree with this, because as most frameworks  seem to be MVC, but probably are [Model 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2).

> In a Model 2 application, requests from the client browser are passed
>   to the controller. The controller performs any logic necessary to
>   obtain the correct content for display. It then places the content in
>   the request (commonly in the form of a JavaBean or POJO) and decides
>   which view it will pass the request to. The view then renders the
>   content passed by the controller.

So if we are going to put these frameworks aside, how do you do your controller then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a series of articles for writing MVC applications, inspired by one of the links you posted. Among those there is an article about Controllers:
[Controllers are taking SRP seriously](http://gobline.com/docs/concepts/mvc/controller)

Have a read at it first.

> So if we are going to put these frameworks aside, how do you do your
>   controller then?

My controllers don't have a reference to the view. They only update the model as shown in your code sample, and I think that's the right way to do. Controllers shouldn't contain binding logic to the view. Instead, the view gets its data from the model (see [The View gets its own data from the Model](http://gobline.com/docs/concepts/mvc/view) where I also explain the advantages of such a design).
Controllers can consume as many dependencies as they want (they might need more than just the model injected), but if you follow SRP closely, controllers won't need a lot of dependencies.

In most popular frameworks, you see a controller with a bunch of actions and binding logic for view rendering; I instead separate all these actions into separate controllers so that I have a 1:1 relationship between controller and view. This allows me to have controllers without binding logic to the view (see link above for detailed explanation on how I do that). My Controllers also follow SRP more closely this way.

When I said above, that the controller updates the model, beware that [MVC Models are not just Domain Models](http://gobline.com/docs/concepts/mvc/model). In addition to Domain Models, *View Models* store the state that the view needs for rendering, e.g.: the view allowing to update an entity like let's say a User, needs to know which user needs to be updated (again, read articles for more detailed explanations).  My Controllers have thus in most cases at least two dependencies,

1. a domain model (most frequently an ORM instance) allowing me to update the datasource
2. a view model allowing me to update the application state (like which user is to be updated, search filters, ...) necessary for view rendering

Comment: `In most popular frameworks, you see a controller with a bunch of actions and binding logic for view rendering;` this is what scares me off from investing too much time into them (even though I started learning Zend...). pro framework guys probably strongly disagree with the minority who tries to do it 'seriously'. i wonder why these frameworks have became the main stream of php development. they almost become a blueprint and guide of php developers. thanks for the answer and links anyway :)

Comment: In the original MVC design pattern it states that the model notifies the view that it must update itself. But that will only work for desktop applications (rich GUI) where all the components are running concurrently. For the web, however, that won't work. And an easy approach that works well, is for the controller to prepare the view. And that's the approach that currently all popular frameworks take.

Comment: Because on the web you'd just render a php template and you reinitialise the whole view for every request (if we do not consider the js frameworks/ajax). Nothing remains in memory. In rich gui clients, all your objects are continuously running and models can notify specific view components (through the observer pattern) for changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not seen Model 2 before this question, but as far as I can tell it is just a Java-specific approach to MVC, it isn't a separate design pattern as such.

You've not really explained why you think the PHP frameworks you mentioned aren't following MVC, in ZF at least it is quite common practice for dependencies to be passed in via. a controller's constructor as you have in the example from your own framework.

It's easy to fall down the rabbit hole with design patterns, really a lot of it is down to interpretation. Just because your implementation of a pattern isn't the same as another, doesn't necessarily mean the other implementation is wrong.